# Home Server REVERSED DNS

Tags: dns, domain

I know what if you want to create reversed DNS you need change DNS servers to domain and in server need park this domain. It is possible to do this at home server ? With basic internet provider ?

Comment: Have you even tried something yet ?

Comment: You might want to correct your grammar, I'm having trouble following what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You ISP controls the reverse DNS for your IP address. You should ask them if they want to change it. If they don't, you're out of luck.

Alternatively you could use a VPN to a VPS or something, at a hosting provider which allows you to change your reverse.